# Duplicate for-loop practice, beginner needs advice to study

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

Understanding the `-1` in the `for` loop, need detailed explanation with `for` and `if` lines of code included?

```
int[] array = { 2, 5, 1, 2, 3, 5 };

Arrays.sort(array); 

// why does this start counting from 1, and if l put 0 it goes to error, out of bounds?
for (int i = 1; i < array.length; i++) { 

    if (array[i] == array[i - 1]) {        // - 1?
        System.out.print(array[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: About the crash:
If you start with `i=0`, it will go out of bounds in the first loop, at `array[i - 1]`, because then `i=0`, so `i-1` will make `-1`: out of bounds.

Comment: yea, coz 5-4 will give -1, that's right?

Comment: `5-4` will never occur because there is no `4` in your code at all. `i` is the only variable that changes, because of the loop. If you start with `0` like this: `for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++)`, then the situation in my first comment will occur: if `i` is `0`, you get: `array[0 - 1]`, effectively accessing the following array index: `array[-1]`, and that is invalid. Like gtgaxiola said, arrays are zero indexed and the first key starts at `0`. Anything below will cause an index out of bounds exception.

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing inherently wrong with it.

It just makes the iteration to start with `i=1` up to the array's length, but since indexing in arrays are zero-based you have to offset it when getting the value.

That is why is `array[i-1]`

If you put `i=0` then you also have to change the ending condition to `array.length-1`, and you have to access the values by `array[i]` in order to avoid going out of bounds.

Comment: metaphorically speaking, when i = 1 (strating from 1 to count, that's number 5 in array) then goes to 6 (that's array.length) .
in if block (array[i] are now 5,1,2,3,5 == to array(i - 1) that is 5,1,2,3,5 now -1?

Comment: @Cleverson no, because you have `Arrays.sort(array)`.  That means the values are in numerical order `{1, 2, 2, 3, 5, 5}`

Answer (score 0):

For questions like this, take the code one line at a time and try to follow what it is doing.

The first thing you do here is to create an array, then sort it. After the `Arrays.sort(array)` call, your `array` will contain the following:

```
index      0 1 2 3 4 5
----------------------
contents   1 2 2 3 5 5
```

Remember, arrays are zero-indexed - that means the very first element is located at index 0. (The *contents* of the array don't matter, it's the *index* you want to pay attention to.)

Arrays *cannot* have indexes less then zero, and they also cannot have indexes greater than their length-1. So, for your example, that means you cannot use -1 as an index because it is less than 0. You also cannot use 6 as an index, since 6 is greater than the length of the array (6) minus one.

In the initialization of the for-loop, you set `i` equal to 1 for the first iteration. Though unconventional, it's perfectly legal. This simply represents which *index* we will start from in the array. So for the first iteration of the loop, `array[i]` will be pointing to the value 2, and `array[i-1]` points to the value 1.

```
index      0 1 2 3 4 5
----------------------
contents   1 2 2 3 5 5
i            ^
i-1        ^
```

Now, what if you set `i` to start at index 0 instead? Well, then `array[i]` will point to the 0th index (value 1)... but what does `array[i-1]` point to?

```
index      0 1 2 3 4 5
----------------------
contents   1 2 2 3 5 5
i          ^ 
i-1      ^
```

It's pointing to index -1. Since arrays can't have indexes of -1, this is causing your IndexOutOfBoundsException. Hopefully that makes sense.